# How do I dump a file every hour with an infinite loop in my program?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am collecting a lot of data and I am reaching the limits of what I want my file size to be. I want to dump a .csv file every hour, but I'm not sure how to do it with the way my program works. Here's the `while` loop I'm working with:

```
with open(
        f'C:\\etc\\etc\\etc',
        'w',
        encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)

    while 1:
        O2line = O2Serial.read_until('\r', size=6)

        CO2line = CO2Serial.read_until('\r', size=4)
        time.sleep(1)

        RedBoardline = RedBoardSerial.read_until()
        RedBoardline = RedBoardline.rstrip()

        try:
            O2line = O2line.decode("utf-8")
            CO2line = CO2line.decode("utf-8")
            RedBoardline = RedBoardline.decode("utf-8")
            RedBoardData = RedBoardline.split(';')
            testTime = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
            nowDate: str = testTime.split(' ').pop(-2)
            nowTime: str = testTime.split(' ').pop()
            row.append(nowDate)
            row.pop(-10)
            row.append(nowTime)
            row.pop(-10)
            row.append(O2line)
            row.pop(-10)
            row.append(CO2line)
            row.pop(-10)
            row.append(RedBoardData[0])
            row.append(RedBoardData[1])
            row.append(RedBoardData[2])
            row.append(RedBoardData[3])
            row.append(RedBoardData[4])
            row.pop(-10)
            row.pop(-10)
            row.pop(-10)
            row.pop(-10)
            row.pop(-10)
            print(row)

            data.append(row)
            writer.writerow(data[i])
            i += 1

        except:
            print("didn't work")
            row = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

It seems like it should be rather simple to do, but the while loop depends on the filename being defined before the start of the loop. I need the loop to stop every hour to create a new file with MM-DD-YYYY_HH;MM;SS in the name. What is the most effective way to achieve this?

Comment: Alternatively, you could write a script that dumps the file, then create a chron job which runs that script hourly

Comment: Why did you not swap the `while` and `with` statements?

Comment: @mkrieger1 your comment helped - feel free to submit it as a separate answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this from the command line would be to use the `watch` command, i.e. `watch -n3600 script.py` where `-n<num seconds between>` indicates how long to wait.

If you store the PID, e.g. `os.getpid()`, then you can just call `os.kill(pid)` at the beginning of the new call, or something of the sort.